# RegEx returns as one result instead of two

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

> #{id:123}#{id:456}

and I am searching for matches using this regular expression:

> /([a-z0-9\:#{}])/

It returns a match from the string, but it only returns one result instead of two.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to acomplish here. Match this string ? Extract id ? Your current regex is rather poor, as it check for only 1 character

Comment: i need to get two matches, #{id:123} and #{id:456}.. but when you test the regular expression it treats the string as one result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var myregex = /#{id:\d+}/g;
var theMatchObject = myregex.exec(yourString);
while (theMatchObject != null) {
    // do something with the match:
    // matched text: theMatchObject[0]
    theMatchObject = myregex.exec(yourString);
}
```

**Explanation**

- `#{id:` matches literal chars
- `\d+` matches one or more ASCII digits
- `}` matches a literal char
- the code iterates through the matches